# How to set the names of columns in dataframe when merging several dataframes together?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns, concatenation

I have several CSV files which I read as dataframe.
I need to create one dataframe which contains all this data from CSV files with appropriate names of colums.

I found this solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'F:\\df_freeq_new_mostfreqpart\\' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ";", index_col=None, usecols = 
    ['Unnamed: 0','counter_routes', 'percent_availability'])
    df.rename( columns={'Unnamed: 0':'meters'}, inplace=True )
    df = df[df.counter_routes>0]
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

And I receive dataframe with all my data but I don't know how can set the names of the column instead of numbers:1,2,3.. 
I want to achieve next:
the original name of the column + the number that is in the name of original CSV file.
The example of the name of the CSV file:

```
"dfFrequeny100_56"
```

for this file I need to have columns like:

```
'counter_routes_56', 'percent_availability_56'
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need value after `_` with split and add to original columns names by `+=`:

```
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ";", index_col=None, usecols = 
    ['Unnamed: 0','counter_routes', 'percent_availability'])
    df.rename( columns={'Unnamed: 0':'meters'}, inplace=True )
    df = df[df.counter_routes>0]
    df.columns += '_' + filename.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
    print (df.head())
    li.append(df)
```

Comment: I tried this solution and have this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: oops, need `df.columns += '_' + filename.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]` instead `df.columns += '_' + filename.str.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]`

Comment: @KaterynaLubyk - I changed `df = df[df.counter_routes>0]` before set columns names and ald add `print (df.head())`, can you check?

Comment: Yes, I made the same. When I do `print (df.head())` in for loop it has correct name of columns. But in the end, `frame `has numerical names of columns

Comment: @Kateryna Lubyk Problem is need remove `ignore_index=True` like `frame = pd.concat(li, axis=1)`

Comment: @ jezrael now it is working, thank you a lot for your help!